# How do I import blob and clob fields from oracle to hbase using sqoop

Tags: hbase, hive, sqoop

How do I import blob and clob fields from oracle to hbase using sqoop

for hbase,  the clob/blob to go under _lobs directory and referenceid to the _lob be in the column family.

Answer (score 0):

By using Sqoop bulk load option we can import blob and clob fields to HBase.

sqoop import -Dsqoop.hbase.add.row.key=true --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:databasename --username ***** --table *** --password ***** --hbase-table **** --column-family cf --columns c1,c2,c3 --hbase-row-key file_id --hbase-create-table --inline-lob-limit 0 --hbase-bulkload --as-sequencefile -m1